# How to unit test a model controller using a singleton

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I went to a boot camp for coding some time ago and while they were very good, they didn't teach anything about unit testing. I've been doing some self-teaching about unit testing and the idea of TDD makes so much sense on why you would do it. I recently went back to some of my old apps and wanted to try unit testing them, but I feel like I can't make heads or tails of it with how they taught. Here is a few bits of code, maybe someone could help me understand how to make sense of this.

Model

```
import Foundation

struct Entry {
    let title: String
    let body: String
}
```

Model Controller

```
import Foundation

class EntryController {
    //Singleton
    static let shared = EntryController()

    //Source of Truth
    var entries: [Entry] = []

    //CRUD functions
    func newEntry(title: String, body: String) {
        let entry = Entry(title: title, body: body)
        entries.append(entry)
    }

    func updateEntry(title: String, body: String, entry: Entry) {
        entry.title = title
        entry.body = body
    }

    func destroyEntry(entry: Entry) {
        guard let index = entries.index(of: entry) else {return}
        entries.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

View Controller

```
import UIKit

class EntryViewController: TableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return EntryController.shared.entries.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entry", for: indexPath) //reuse identifier declared on storyboard
        let entry = EntryController.shared.entries[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel.text = entry.title
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = entry.body
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

There's a bit more code than this, but I put up what effectively amounts to three different files of code here. The question I have is how would I test the crud functions in the singleton. Is there more that I should test than just the CRUD functions, does unit testing cover more than just testing individual functions? And if I made the CRUD functions static instead, how would those be unit tested instead. Also, how does one unit test a UIViewController? I've done more than a little searching online, but I'm really struggling to make sense of the answers, in part because the answers are given on a much higher level than I am.

Any help would be appreciated.

.....

Edit: I should mention that I think I understand how to mock a class and create Protocols to be inherited from for both the production class and the mocked class if that helps.

Comment: singleton is a first thing to be removed when you need to write tests. google for dependency injection

Comment: I just got off the phone with a friend who does professional iOS development. This question was asked and we basically had a ~2 hour conversation about it. I thought I understood dependency injection, but I definitely didn't despite several hours of google already. Gotta say, the way I learned is not conducive to unit testing at all.

Comment: It’s not easy, especially when you only start learning it, that’s true. Bus saying it’s not conducive? First google search “dependency injection unit testing” gives this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/140994